# How can I edit my code to exclude capital letters A to Z?

Tags: c++

Starts with 0 -> 9 -> A -> Z -> a -> z then begins the next sequence of 00 -> zz

I'd like to remove the A -> Z section of my code so the output goes from 0 -> 9 -> a -> z without counting A -> Z.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void Crack(string password, vector<char> Chars)
{
    cout<<"PASSWORD TO CRACK: "<<password<<endl;
    int n = Chars.size();
    int i = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        i++;
        int N = 1;
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)N*=n;
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            int K = 1;
            string crack = "";
            for(int k=0;k<i;k++)
            {
                crack += Chars[j/K%n];
                K *= n;
            }
            cout<< "Testing PASS: "<<crack<<" "<<"against "<<password<<endl;
            if(password.compare(crack) == 0){
                cout<<"Cracked password: "<<crack<<endl;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<char> Chars;
    for(char c = '0';c<='z';c++){
        if(isalpha(c) || isdigit(c))Chars.push_back(c);
    }
    Crack("zzzzzzzz", Chars);
}
```

Comment: Use the API `isalpha` combined with `isupper` or `islower`.

Comment: Please indent your code properly so it's actually readable. You should clarify what you are doing. Are you talking about the `for (char c= '0'; c <= z;c++)` part of your code, like you don't want to have `A` through `Z` handled?

Answer (score 0):

You just do:

```
for(char c = '0'; c <= '9'; c++)
    Chars.push_back(c);
for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
    Chars.push_back(c);
```

By the way, what you're trying to do can be accomplished much easier with the use of recursion.